# Powershell connect Home drive

Tags: powershell

this script works good

```
Get-ADUser -filter * | % { Set-ADUser $_ -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory ('\\Server \home$\' + $_.SamAccountName) }
```

But as soon as i add if not variable its not working not sure whats going wrong with it

```
ForEach( $User in (Get-ADUser -filter *  | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName ) ){ if( -not ( HomeDrive "H:" HomeDirectory ('\\server\home$\' + $_.SamAccountName)) | Set-ADUser $_ -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory('\\HYDAD1\home$\' + $_.SamAccountName))  }
```

Comment: `-HomeDrive` and `-HomeDirectory` are parameters to `Set-ADUser` and you can't use them like that in your second version. You need all the properties of the user account, so you can check `$user.HomeDirectory` which means you can't use `-ExpandProperty` either, because that loses all the other user account properties. And you can't really use `if () | ` you need to use `if () {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I now it works

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where{$_.Home -ne "H:" -or $_.HomeDirectory -ne ('\\server\home$\' + $_.SamAccountName)}) | % { Set-ADUser $_ -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory ('\\Server \home$\' + $_.SamAccountName) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a little help with syntax, and maybe some structure. As noted in the comment above, `Home` and `HomeDirectory` are properties of the user object. In order to be able to access them you can not use `Select -Expand samaccountname` beforehand, as that will simply pass the user's alias as a string down the pipe to be used, and it will not include those properties. So we'll start by removing that bit. Next you have to reference them as properties correctly by referencing your variable `$user`. That would look like `$user.home -ne "H:"` and `$user.HomeDirectory -ne ('\\server\home$\' + $user.SamAccountName)`. You'll notice that I also added `-eq` to both of those. That is the comparison operator for not-equals. That cleans up your syntax a bit, now let's look at structure.

Instead of piping to an `If` statement, let's use a `Where` statement to filter out only the users that need attention. Since we're doing it this way you use `$_` instead of `$user` since we haven't actually made it into the `ForEach` loop yet. So that would look like:

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where{$_.Home -ne "H:" -or $_.HomeDirectory -ne ('\\server\home$\' + $_.SamAccountName)})
```

Now if you incorporate that into your script it looks like this:

```
ForEach( $User in (Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where{$_.Home -ne "H:" -or $_.HomeDirectory -ne ('\\server\home$\' + $_.SamAccountName)}) ){  
    Set-ADUser $User -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory('\\HYDAD1\home$\' + $_.SamAccountName)  
}
```

Comment: Let me test on test ad server, Where{$_.Home -ne "H:" -or $_.HomeDirectory -ne this looks good it will not connect home directory if not exists.

Comment: Is this also going to work @themadTechnician 

ForEach( $User in (Get-ADUser -Filter * |  Where{$_.ScriptPath 'yyy.bat -ne | Set-ADUser -ScriptPath 'yyy.bat'

Comment: No, that will not work. You have the order wrong. Read it out loud... that reads "Where the ScriptPath property 'yyy.bat' does not equal". It should be "Where the ScriptPath property does not equal 'yyy.bat'" so change it to `Get-ADUser -filter * | Where{$_.ScriptPath -ne 'yyy.bat'} | Set-ADUser -ScriptPath 'yyy.bat'`

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted so that future users can find it for help.